# URL signature expired error when viewing Instagram images from Instagram API

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I am getting the instagram images from instagram API. (endpoint : https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token= ). Then I am saving the image URLs that returning from the API call in the database and use them in the front-end. Exmple image url is below.

Example URL : https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/vp/xxx/xxx/xx/s150x150/xxx/x.x.x.x/xxxx_n.jpg

But sometimes the images doesn't show and when I go to the image particular link it shows 'URL signature expired'. What would be the reason for that?

I have referred the question about the same in a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668014/instagram-feed-api-media-url-shows-url-signature-expired) in stack overflow and it didn't help. It said to save the image in a separate server. It won't work for me.

Answer (score 15):

You can visit https://www.instagram.com/p/CQX8lKutaZU/media/?size=l

Use;
"l" parameter for large,

"m" parameter for medium,

"t" parameter for small pictures.

But sadly it doesn't work on videos (it just shows thumbnails)

Comment: Very helpful! Is there something similar for user profile picture?

Comment: How can we specify the image we want in a multi-image post?

Answer (score 8):

Instagram CDN URLs contain timestamp components that allow them to expire after a while. If you need the image to persist, you'll have to save it somewhere and serve that instead.

Comment: @BertH It is not. See https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/ - specifically this bit that implies storing is OK. "If you store or cache User Content, keep it up to date. For example, if a user marks a photo as 'private', you must reflect that change by removing the content as soon as reasonably possible."

Comment: The best way is to get the updated image URL through a cron job once every 4 or 5 days.