# Video URLs from Instagram API Expire and break after a short period of time

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

After a short timeframe, Instagram updates the image URL and the one they give you becomes expired. It isn't a scheduled thing so it isn't something you can refetch on a schedule to fix. The URL you have may break at any time. Has anyone found a solution to easily retrieve an Instagram video URL perhaps similar to the way that the linked solution fetches a current version of static images?

Here is an example of an expired URL that comes from the Instagram API:
https://video-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t50.33967-16/311796704_656982995824312_2200462786629368413_n.mp4?_nc_cat=100&vs=415717487387323_1550039796&_nc_vs=HBksFQAYJEdPQ2psUks0N2hiR2hWVUNBRjE2Z3ZJX25Za2VicV9FQUFBRhUAAsgBABUAGCRHRGw4alJKMmxkNUFBTU1CQU0wMG1qVU5adW9XYnFfRUFBQUYVAgLIAQAoABgAGwGIB3VzZV9vaWwBMRUAACb8mv6DgfHqQBUCKAJDMywXQBIFHrhR64UYEmRhc2hfYmFzZWxpbmVfMV92MREAdQAA&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=59939d&efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6InZ0c192b2RfdXJsZ2VuLjcyMC5jbGlwcyJ9&_nc_ohc=nav3pTRz9T0AX-csieO&_nc_ht=video-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com&edm=AL-3X8kEAAAA&oh=00_AT9Wj2ue0CNOvRywTzAh2gvCxJl9Bhr1me4nIveXwZ2KNg&oe=634A481F&_nc_rid=6e1aabaa0c

This problem is specifically for Instagram Videos. The same thing happens to images and we are using the solution from this post: [Instagram/feed API media URL shows 'URL signature expired'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668014/instagram-feed-api-media-url-shows-url-signature-expired) to fix static images and video poster images. But this doesn't work for video.

We've also tried the suggestions of using parameters ?__a=1 but it comes up as a broken page and does not return json as some have suggested.

Currently we are falling back to the poster image, but having the video would obviously be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there is a definitive answer to your problem from what I can find however there is a similar question that has an answer located in this post: [Instagram Media Without Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49852080/is-there-currently-anyway-to-fetch-instagram-user-media-without-authentication)

Summarized answer: You have to use both arguments "__a=1" and "__d=dis" in the url. This answer seems to be the generally accepted answer.

Instagram is always changing their API so you may end up with broken links in the future again regardless of what you do.